# Subsurface modifier messing up texture on cloth simulation

Tags: modeling, materials, cloth-simulation

I don't know why this is happening but I had a cloth sim for this skirt working fine and texturing fine... but I added a subsurface modifier under the cloth physics to add some extra resolution (as I saw in a cloth tutorial) - which worked great, but it's messed up the texture. I tried adding more loop cuts but that messed it up even more... Any ideas? But the texture is fine without the extra subsurf... and I tried UV unwrapping after this too and everything I can think of.

Sorry if I didn't post this in the right place... I am new here!

What has happened (wrong):
[image: What has happened (wrong)]

Problem::
[image: Problem]

How it should look (but this is when the *Subdivision Surface* modifier is off and has less resolution):
[image: How it should look (but this is when the subsurf is off and has less resolution)]

Image 4:
[image]

Project file: https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/55bf93c2-fecd-43e8-b7ea-b49b3a0e5eff

Comment: Have you checked the face orientation? Maybe there are a few flipped?

Comment: Can you provide the file. Just the cloth and the textures will do it

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've checked the face orientation and it seems they are all fine... I'm trying to figure out how to upload the file...

Comment: Hi I uploaded the project file here: https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/55bf93c2-fecd-43e8-b7ea-b49b3a0e5eff

Comment: In Blender 3.0 I cannot see these shading issues. Which version do you use? How much memory does your PC have? Your blend file is very big (I wonder why). There is a high-poly sculpt included. But 1.2 GB is a lot. When the file is open it consumes 6 GB, with the particle hair visible it's 13 GB. Maybe something runs out of memory? You could try to append the low-poly version to a new file (File > Append...). But first, remove the Shrinkwrap modifier so the high-poly version is not appended as well.